# Can a particular table(or class) may have multiple one-to-one as well as one-to-many relationship with other tables(or classes)?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Can a particular table(or class) may have multiple one-to-one as well as one-to-many relationship with other tables(or classes)?

For eg- Right now I am developing a banking application and I have a UserDetails table which have a primary key as userId. Now I am using this userId as a foreign key in various other tables such as Transactions, BalanceInfo, AccountDetails, etc where UserDetails can be associated as one-to-one as well as many-to-one relationship. So is this the correct way of implementation? Also what will happen if I don't associate them with any kind of relationships and later associate them with just the foreign key constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes, you can have as many relationships as you can create.

As for whether it is the correct way, that depends on the conditions on which the system needs to work.  If UserDetails is an important part of each of those other objects in your domain, and they need UserDetails to function, then sure, it is fine.

If you keep PK and FK constraints in the DB and do not make Hibernate aware of them, then you may violate them without proper coding.  If you make them lazy-loaded, then the relationship exists but you do not have to load the data into your application.

The real aswer as to if this is correct could only come after proper analysis of your domain model, so that is something you will have to decide.